# CSS: Centering an image. Why doesn't 'text-align: center'?

Tags: html, css

I've got to center an image within a div-container with fixed sizes.

My first idea was: img is an inline-element. So you can use `text-align: center`. As with text.

But that doesn't work.

I've made this demo:

```css
.wrap {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: lightGrey;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.wrap img {
  border-radius: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrap p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="https://placebear.com/200/300" alt="bild" />
  <p>Just a little bit of placeholder-text.</p>
</div>
```

One can see: Text centering works perfectly. But image centering fails.

**What did I do wrong here? Respectively: Which of my assumptions are wrong?**

Comment: Try to add text-align: center to .wrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text-align` affects the inline **content** of an element.

The image isn't the content of the `<img>`, it is the `<img>`.

For `text-align` to affect it, you must apply the property to the *parent* of the `<img>`.

Comment: Silly me. Perhaps my question will help someone else making the same mistake. Lots of thanks to all you folks answering.

Answer (score 3):

```
.wrap {
  text-align: center;
}
```

use this

Answer (score 1):

hi img is inline eliment so you can not add text-align: center; to image
add parent div to check this

```css
.wrap {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: lightGrey;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrap img {
  border-radius: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrap p {
  
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="https://placebear.com/200/300" alt="bild" />
  <p>Just a little bit of placeholder-text.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your .wrap class should have text-align: center

```css
.wrap {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: lightGrey;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrap img {
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.wrap p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="https://placebear.com/200/300" alt="bild" />
  <p>Just a little bit of placeholder-text.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to your CSS

```
img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
```

Thus it should be :

```
.wrap img {
  border-radius: 12px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
```

Or you can also add `text-align:center` to `.wrap`

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/2266/):

Answer (score 1):

Add style in  **wrap** in class   `text-align: center;`

```css
.wrap {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: lightGrey;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrap img {
  border-radius: 12px;     
}

.wrap p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="https://placebear.com/200/300" alt="bild" />
  <p>Just a little bit of placeholder-text.</p>
</div>
```